Calculating a Feynman diagram with the helicity basis
In the book by Peskin and Schroeder, they calculate the leading order diagram for the process $e^- e^+ \to \mu^- \mu^+$ (see page 136 for the labelling of the momenta). They do this in two ways: using Dirac algebra and by defining explicit expressions for the fermion polarizations. I have been trying to use the second method, but slightly different from what they do. I keep getting an answer that is different from what it should be and I hope that there is anybody who can identify my mistake(s).
The amplitude is given by
$$
\mathrm{i}\mathcal{M} = \bar{v}_-(p')(-\mathrm{i} e\gamma^\mu)u_+(p)\left(\frac{-\mathrm{i} g_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}\right)\bar{u}_+(k)(-\mathrm{i} e\gamma^\nu)v_-(k')
$$
Peskin and Schroeder make use of a short cut, where they calculate the first vertex, which they then rotate with an angle $\theta$, such that the outgoing polarization bispinors can then be aligned with the $3$-direction again.
Instead, I would like to perform this calculation using the helicity basis from here, in the high-energy limit where $|\mathbf{p}| = E$,
$$
u_s(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{E - s|\mathbf{p}|}\xi_s(\hat{\mathbf{p}}) \\
        \sqrt{E + s|\mathbf{p}|}\xi_s(\hat{\mathbf{p}})
    \end{pmatrix},
    \qquad
    v_s(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
        -s\sqrt{E + s|\mathbf{p}|}\xi^{-s}(\hat{\mathbf{p}}) \\
        s\sqrt{E - s|\mathbf{p}|}\xi^{-s}(\hat{\mathbf{p}})
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For the right-handed electron and muon and the left-handed positron and antimuon and $\phi = 0$ for the incoming particles, I get polarizations
$$
u_+(p) = \sqrt{2E}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{pmatrix},
    \qquad
    v_-(p') = \sqrt{2E}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1
    \end{pmatrix},
    \qquad
    u_+(k) = \sqrt{2E}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\ 0 \\ \cos\tfrac{\theta}{2} \\ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}
    \end{pmatrix},
    \qquad
    v_-(k') = \sqrt{2E}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\ 0 \\ -\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2} \\ -\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The first vertex yields the same answer as in the book:
$$\bar{v}_-(p')\gamma^\mu u_+(p) = -2E(0, 1, \mathrm{i}, 0).$$
The second vertex is never calculated in the book using this helicity basis, since they use a short cut. I get an expression
$$\bar{v}_-(p')\gamma^\nu u_+(p) = -2E
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2\cos\phi\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2} \\
        2\sin\phi\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2} \\
        \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix}^\mathsf{T}.$$
By taking the Lorentzian product of the two vertices, I get that the amplitude is proportional to
$$ \mathrm{i}\mathcal{M} \propto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2}. $$
Here my answer differs from the book, which says that $\mathcal{M}\propto 1 + \cos\theta$.

$1+\cos\vartheta=2\cos^2\frac\vartheta2$; you might be pretty close.

I found my mistake; the other outgoing particle has an angle $\theta + \pi$ and not also $\theta$. Then the polarization bispinor acquires a phase of $\pi/2$. This answer was based on this post.
